# Sign Identity Server 4 tokens using HS256

Tags: identityserver4

I have an existing api that generates and uses jwt's with a header as follows

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

The api uses JWT bearer authentication

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AllowedAudiences = new[] { "Any" },
    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
    {
        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
    }
});
```

I now want to use identity server for a client I want to integrate with.
How can I get Identity server to sign the token in the way that the existing api expects it (HS256).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IdentityServer does not support symmetric keys.